# Generate HTML Ordered List Elements based on values in a JavaScript Object Literal Within Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, html-lists, javascript-objects

I am trying to generate content using values from the skills section of my JavaScript array based on the value of my drop down menu in my html. I am not sure the best way to go about and do this. I have generated the Title, Description, and Image just fine, but I know the skills section will need to be done differently to get it into an Ordered List. Below is my HTML code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WernickeKevin_Assignment1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <select id="infoChange">
            <option value="0">Digital Design 1</option>
            <option value="1">Interactive Production 1</option>
            <option value="2">Motion Graphics 1</option>
            <option value="3">Web Programming 1</option>
        </select>

        <div>
            <h1></h1>   
            <p></p>
            <ol>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ol>
            <img src="">
        </div>  

    </body>
    <script src="js/courses.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript File containing my Array with Objects and some other code. Note: I am trying to generate the values in the skills section in an ordered html list.

```
    var courses = [

    {
        name: 'Digital Design 1',
        code: '(WEBD 111)',
        description: 'This course introduces students to colour theory, typography, layout and visual hierarchy. These principles are presented as part of a universal set of techniques that are applied across design disciplines and reinforced through examples from numerous fields. Students are introduced to the language of design as well as the foundational design process.',
        skills: ['Photoshop', 'Illustrator', 'Wireframing'],
        image: 'images/image1.jpg'
    },

    {
        name: 'Interactive Production 1',
        code: '(WEBD 112)',
        description: 'Through a series of case studies, students will be given a high-level overview of all of the component pieces of an interactive project. Each stage of a project is analyzed with an emphasis on design as a problem-solving process. Topics include the role of interactive design, team roles, and project planning.',
        skills: ['JavaScript', 'Objects', 'Functions'],
        image: 'images/image2.png'
    },

    {
        name: 'Motion Graphics 1',
        code: '(WEBD 113)',
        description: 'Throughout this course, students are exposed to the discipline of motion graphics on the web. The focus of this course is the creation of animated and dynamic interactive media for web and multimedia applications. Students are taught a variety of techniques that enable the creation of effective motion graphics projects that support the message to be delivered by the completed project, and are appropriate for the medium. Students also learn how to animate objects, create symbols and assemble motion graphics projects for delivery to a variety of media, ranging from mobile devices to home entertainment systems.',
        skills: ['CSS Transitions', '-webkit-', 'keyframing'],
        image: 'images/image4.png'
    },

    {
        name: 'Web Programming 1',
        code: '(WEBD 120)',
        description: 'This course provides learners with a fundamental understanding of the concepts that underpin client-side web programming for both desktop and mobile platforms. Through a series of hands-on exercises, students will learn how to design, build and deploy standards-compliant web pages using appropriate technologies and tools.',
        skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Semantics'],
        image: 'images/image4.png'
    }
];

    //Grab value of html options in the select tag, and use them as index values for the array

var e = document.getElementById("infoChange");
var index = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = courses[index].name + ' ' + courses[index].code;
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = courses[index].description;
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = courses[index].image;
```

Comment: templaters like mustache are really handy for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of how the page and courses are set up, there are always three skills per course, and three preset `<li>` placeholders. So you can simply assign each of the `li` elements to the corresponding skill in the `skills` array:

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].innerHTML = courses[index].skills[0];
  document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].innerHTML = courses[index].skills[1];
  document.getElementsByTagName('li')[2].innerHTML = courses[index].skills[2];
```

Though I find it ugly to repeat code. A for loop from 0 to 2 inclusive would work, but other ranges would not correspond to the three `<li>`s in the HTML. The other alternative I thought of is to change the list structure by clearing the `ol` and inserting for each course skill, with a function such as

```
function insertSkill(skillText) {
  var newSkill = document.createElement("li");
  var newSkillText = document.createTextNode(skillText);
  newSkill.appendChild(newSkillText);
  document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].appendChild(newSkill);
}
```

```js
var courses = [

  {
    name: 'Digital Design 1',
    code: '(WEBD 111)',
    description: 'This course introduces students to colour theory, typography, layout and visual hierarchy. These principles are presented as part of a universal set of techniques that are applied across design disciplines and reinforced through examples from numerous fields. Students are introduced to the language of design as well as the foundational design process.',
    skills: ['Photoshop', 'Illustrator', 'Wireframing'],
    image: 'images/image1.jpg'
  },

  {
    name: 'Interactive Production 1',
    code: '(WEBD 112)',
    description: 'Through a series of case studies, students will be given a high-level overview of all of the component pieces of an interactive project. Each stage of a project is analyzed with an emphasis on design as a problem-solving process. Topics include the role of interactive design, team roles, and project planning.',
    skills: ['JavaScript', 'Objects', 'Functions'],
    image: 'images/image2.png'
  },

  {
    name: 'Motion Graphics 1',
    code: '(WEBD 113)',
    description: 'Throughout this course, students are exposed to the discipline of motion graphics on the web. The focus of this course is the creation of animated and dynamic interactive media for web and multimedia applications. Students are taught a variety of techniques that enable the creation of effective motion graphics projects that support the message to be delivered by the completed project, and are appropriate for the medium. Students also learn how to animate objects, create symbols and assemble motion graphics projects for delivery to a variety of media, ranging from mobile devices to home entertainment systems.',
    skills: ['CSS Transitions', '-webkit-', 'keyframing'],
    image: 'images/image4.png'
  },

  {
    name: 'Web Programming 1',
    code: '(WEBD 120)',
    description: 'This course provides learners with a fundamental understanding of the concepts that underpin client-side web programming for both desktop and mobile platforms. Through a series of hands-on exercises, students will learn how to design, build and deploy standards-compliant web pages using appropriate technologies and tools.',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Semantics'],
    image: 'images/image4.png'
  }
];

//Grab value of html options in the select tag, and use them as index values for the array

var e = document.getElementById("infoChange");
e.addEventListener("change", updateInfo);

function updateInfo() {
  var index = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = courses[index].name + ' ' + courses[index].code;
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = courses[index].description;
  document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = courses[index].image;
  document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].innerHTML = courses[index].skills[0];
  document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].innerHTML = courses[index].skills[1];
  document.getElementsByTagName('li')[2].innerHTML = courses[index].skills[2];
}

function clearSkills() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].innerHTML = "";
}

function insertSkill(skillText) {
  var newSkill = document.createElement("li");
  var newSkillText = document.createTextNode(skillText);
  newSkill.appendChild(newSkillText);
  document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].appendChild(newSkill);
}

updateInfo();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>WernickeKevin_Assignment1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <select id="infoChange">
    <option value="0">Digital Design 1</option>
    <option value="1">Interactive Production 1</option>
    <option value="2">Motion Graphics 1</option>
    <option value="3">Web Programming 1</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" onclick="insertSkill('my new skill')" value="Append Skill">
  <input type="button" onclick="clearSkills()" value="Clear  all Skills">
  <div>
    <h1></h1> 
    <p></p>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
    <img src="">
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/courses.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome! I just thought of another way: a for loop from 0-2. Pick a method that suits you best.